# Running a code in special time

Tags: php, time

How can I run a code in especial time ? let me explain you, think a inserted a time about future in database, now i want run a code 15 min before that time. Does my site need to be loaded to check is now 15 min before the inserted time in database to run the code?
Any suggestion can be useful.

Comment: cron job ..........

Comment: Do you mean from a web page? (php tag makes me think that).  Do you mean run a job against your database and do something NOT a web page?  What database is this?  Please add a LOT more detail and what you have tried.

Comment: CRON jon is the answer

Comment: create a php script to run your task. Run a cron job every minute to check the date and time stored in DB and if the current time is 15 minutes before the stored time run your code else do nothing. You can set the cron job for every minute. As suggested by others cron job is the solution.

Comment: @markSchultheiss think: I share a product in my website. it's purchase time is tomorrow night at 23:00 now i want send an email to my site's users 15 min before the purchase time. my database is mysql.

Comment: You need to setup CRON for that. Whenever your cron runs it will compare current time is 15 min before purchase time or not. and do needful action.